# Array in for loop, C99

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop

I asked a previous question about declaring an array in a for loop, e.g.

```
for(i=0;i<=1000;i++){
    float arrayone[(length[i])];
    do a bunch of other stuff
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to do an array whose length can be varied based on what step the program is on. I don't want to keep the array data saved permanently (like arrayone[][]), since it's big and there's lots of steps.

So I was told it's legal to declare the array only within this scope like this. **But will it try to store 1000 copies of the array by the end, which I don't want?** I'm a beginner, so I don't understand the nuances of what the blocks really do.

The alternative for me is just to make an array outside of the loop which has the maximum length ever needed, and to overwrite that at every step.

Edit: The use for the array is: I have a global array. The arrays in the loop are filled with function results using that global array, to save computing. The arrays get manipulated,...,...,and finally are used to change the global array. Then they're not needed anymore.

Comment: Go with your alternative solution

Comment: Do you actually ask a question?  I don't see one.

Comment: It would be a good idea to share what the array does, maybe there is a better way to do it than that.

Comment: @abelenky "But will it try to store 1000 copies of the array by the end, which I don't want?" I think this is a perfectly valid question unworthy of a downvote.

Answer (score 7):

> But will it try to store 1000 copies of the array by the end, which I don't want?

No, at the beginning of each iteration a new array will be allocated, and, since the array goes out of scope at the end of the iteration, at that time it will be deallocated, so only one array exists at one time.

That is the point of automatic variables (which that array is). At the end of the scope in which they are declared (usually but not always delimited by braces) they are automatically deallocated.

Comment: Thanks! I think that's all I needed to know.

Answer (score 0):

After each iteration of your loop is done all the variables that were declared inside your loop will be destroyed, including your array.  So only one copy of your array will be kept.

That being said, however, you should know that initializing the array outside your loop is probably better, because you won't have to allocate memory on the stack every iteration.

If you were dynamically allocating your array (which you're not in your example) like this:

```
    for(i=0;i<=1000;i++){
      float * arrayone = (float*)malloc(i * sizeof(float));
    }
```

then you have a problem.  Here the local variable is the pointer, which when it gets destroyed you can no longer access the memory you allocated.  This is the case where you would end up with 1000 different arrays in memory at once.  You could `free` your memory before the pointer is destroyed, but I maintain that having the array declared outside the loop is still better.

Comment: Allocating memory on the stack is very cheap, and if you allocate it outside the loop, then you have to add the complexity of finding the largest number in the array, if that's not already known.

Comment: @Seth If by finding the largest number in the array you mean determining the array size that's not added complexity, since you have to know the size of the array to create it. Everything else is exactly the same whether you declared the array inside the loop or outside. As for the cheapness, how much cheaper is it then not allocating the memory every iteration?

Comment: No, I mean you have to find the largest number that `length` holds, because you'll need the array to be the size of the largest number in the `length` array so that you can create an array large enough to encompass any array you would have created inside the loop (note that the length of each array is calculated as `length[i]`). Also, allocating memory on the stack is usually one assembly instruction.